# Resuming Android app from Notification

Tags: android, notifications, instantiation

How do I resume an Android app from Notification? I want to be able to resume the instance from where it left, with all bounded Services, and settings etc. Instead of a complete new instance. This is my code:

```
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                                                    getSystemService(ns);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MeasurementsStarter.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                                                    this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        // the next two lines initialize the Notification, using the configurations
        // above
        notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Metingen draaien",System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(getBaseContext(), "Metingen ManDown", "Metingen Mandown draaien nog",
                                                                    contentIntent);
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;   
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        final int HELLO_ID = 1;
        mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of found an answer, I manually set the data from all of my textFields etc. and just put my bindService in my onCreate() method. It's propably not the most graceous way, but it works nonetheless